# how to get hive output in variable?

Tags: hadoop, hive

How to get hive query result into one variable? In SQL we use the below query.

```
Declare @cnt as int Select @cnt= count(*) from tabname
```

The @cnt will be used throughout the procedure.
I don't know how to achieve the same in HIVE. Can someone tell me how to achieve this in hive prompt and Shell prompt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, that's pretty straightforward.
In your shell,

```
countinfo=$(hdfs dfs -cat <-directory location}->) 

**hive -hivevar countNum="$countinfo" \
     -f '/Filepath/file.hql' **
```

Inside your file.hql use this `${countNum}` in your query.

Comment: can you please elaborate on the syntax?  execute script that contains `countinfo=$(hdfs dfs -cat /user/tmp)` next line of script `hive -hivevar countNum="$countinfo" \ -f '/user/tmp/file.hql'` THEN in .hql `${countNum} = select max(idCol) from myTable` ??

Answer (score 2):

```html
last_processed_time=`hive -S -e "USE db; select MAX(processed_time) from job_details where event_id = 'XXXX'"`

`echo $last_processed_time
pig -useHCatalog -Dmapred.job.queue.name=highPriority -Dtez.queue.name=highPriority -x tez -param last_processed_time=$last_processed_time test.pig`

> After executing above shell , It displays the required MAX value as
> well as pass the same value to Pig as external parameter for internal
> use within pig. Hope this will be helpful to make the same case with
> hive call using 'hiveconf'
```

Answer (score 0):

There is No straightforward way to do this....

1. One naive way thru shell is:

   `catchData=$(beeline/hive -u jdbc:hive2://$hiveServer2:10000 -n $userName -e "select count(*) from table")`

But this is not effective, as it will print even the hive connect statements, info & warn statements along with the data

**2. The best way would be..**

```
INSERT OVERWRITE DIRECTORY <-directory location}->
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE

countinfo=$(hdfs dfs -cat <-directory location}->)
```

hope this point 2 helps...

Comment: Thanks for your answer . sorry still I did not understand how can I get countinfo value in hiveconf variable.     countinfo=$(hdfs dfs -cat <-directory location}->) how to put this command in my source file (.hql) file.

Comment: Well, that's pretty straightforward...

In your shell,
countinfo=$(hdfs dfs -cat <-directory location}->) 

hive -hivevar countNum="$countinfo" \
     -f '/Filepath/file.hql'
  
Inside your file.hql use this ${countNum} in your query

Answer (score 0):

It's little difficult to do it shell script.

Might I suggest you use Perl script?
Cause in Perl its fairly easy.

You can do it like this in Perl script.

```
$query_total_recs ="SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash -e
hive -e "use schema_name; INSERT OVERWRITE DIRECTORY '/tmp/ank' row format delimited 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' select * from table_name limit 1;"

a=$(hdfs dfs -cat /tmp/ank/000000_0)
echo $a
```

This will give comma separated output of first row from table in variable a